# What datatype is this and how do I get values out of it?

Tags: c#, json, object

I have a value. It looks like a JSON or something. I want to get the values out of it, but it seems that no matter what I try, it errors. I put a debugger on it and this is the value outputted from the debugger:

> {{\n  "question": "hi",\n  "luisResult": {\n    "intent": "get-person-info",\n    "answer": null,\n    "confidenceLevel": 0.9553092\n  },\n  "qnaResult": {\n    "answer": null,\n    "confidenceLevel": 0\n  },\n  "aiResult": null,\n  "likeUnLike": true,\n  "isAnswered": false\n}}

I tried to just call the values in it (like `.question`) but that errors:

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'question' and no accessible extension method 'question' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried running `.GetType()` on it and it returned: `{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}`. I looked up the [documentation for `JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and I see there is a property `.First`. So I call that and it errors:

> error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'First' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I tried to call it as a function (`.First()`) and it errors:

> error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no accessible extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Though all I want to do is get the values in that JSON object (or whatever it is). How do I get values out of it?

### Edit:

The value I'm trying to parse was created using an external package. They call my function and pass in this value. The definition for it is:

```cs
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets a value that is associated with the activity.
JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public object Value { get; set; } // this is the value I'm trying to read
```

Comment: You're describing your code in English. Can you show us actual code instead?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are only a bazillion examples of working with JSON from C# on the web.

Comment: @SamAxe If the information isn't on Stack Overflow, its on topic. If it *is* on Stack Overflow, please vote to close as duplicate instead.

Comment: I added the definition for the variable I'm trying to parse in my original post.

Comment: OK, you're assigning the value to a property of type `Object`, and then trying to use JObject properties on a reference to `Object`. That won't work in a strongly typed language. You're still hiding critically important information, but you can probably declare Value to be `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` and it'll work fine. `First` is a property, not a method, as documented. You had that right the first time, just with the wrong type for the reference.

Comment: @EdPlunkett If that object is in the external package he may not have that option. A safe cast afterwards is OK of course. OP: You probably want to use `ToObject<T>` (in the ideal case) or the index operator to get values out, not `.First`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yes, I think you're right -- he does seem to mean it's the property that's defined elsewhere.

Comment: @AskYous I think Bradley's right, you'll need to cast it like `var jsonObj = (blah.Value as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject);` -- `blah` being the thing that has the `Value` property which references the JSON object. `jsonObj` will be typed correctly to access all the JSON stuff.

Comment: Or if you have C#7:  `if (blah.Value is JObject jsonObj)` :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Our IT people haven't upgraded our build server past VS2012. We can't have nice things. Pbtthththt.

Comment: Thank you @EdPlunkett. That casting solved my issue.

Comment: @AskYous Excellent! You really should use Bradley's if/is construct. Since `Value` is declared as object instead of what it is, I would be suspicious of it potentially being something else sometimes. There could be other reasons, though. Hopefully it's documented.